# Ionic 3 angularfire2 print out [object Object] data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2, angularfire5

I have a task management apps where i wan't user **to be able to see their task in each of the task sections** just like in the photo: [Click here to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX0S6.png)

I can get the data from the database and print it out in JSON format as you can see in the photo where i labeled it as **"task get from database"**, but the problems is I cannot display it like the **"Demo only"** where you can see in the photo.

I'm using **angularfire2** to get the data from firebase realtime-database.

Here are the **console** for the data: [The console of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyibq.png)

Here are the code from provider:

```
getTaskSectionAndTaskList(projBoardKey) {
    this.taskSectNTaskListRef = this.afDatabase.list('taskSection/' + projBoardKey);

    return this.taskSectNTaskListRef;
}
```

Here are the code from .ts file:

```
...
taskList$: Observable<Task[]>;

constructor(..., private tasksecProvider: TasksectionProvider) {
    ...

    this.taskList$ = this.tasksecProvider.getTaskSectionAndTaskList(this.selectedBoardKey)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
            key: c.payload.key,
            ...c.payload.val()
        }));
    });
}
```

Here are the code for HTML file:

```
<div *ngFor="let taskSectionList of taskList$ | async">
    <ion-slide>
        <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>
                <p class="task-section-title">{{ taskSectionList.taskSectionTitle }}</p>
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
                <div>
                    <div class="for-demo-only">
                        <div>
                            <p>Task Name</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{ taskSectionList.task | json }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-card-content>
        <ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problems by using pipes:

Here are the code for the pipes:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the GettaskPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
   name: 'gettask',
})
export class GettaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
  transform(obj: any) {

    let tempResult = [];
    let result = [];

    for (var key in obj.task) {
      if (obj.task.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.push({
            key: key,
            ...obj.task[key]
        });
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Here is what i made a changes to the HTML file:

```
<div *ngFor="let taskSectionList of taskList$ | async">
<ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
            <p class="task-section-title">{{ taskSectionList.taskSectionTitle }}</p>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <div>
                <div class="for-demo-only">
                    <div>
                        <p>Task Name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngFor="let task of taskSectionList | gettask">
                    {{ task.taskName }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-card-content>
    <ion-card>
</ion-slide>
```

Now i can get the task name to be displayed like the demo, just need to apply some css to it then it will look like that already.